# Mysql: new user access denied to database

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm using Mysql 5.5. I logged in mysql by root and created a new user. 
Then I logged in using

```
mysql -u newuser -p
```

Then in mysql I entered

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db1.tablename TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

in order to access to the databases.
But there is an error message:

```
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT,INSERT,UP command denied to user 'newuser'@'localhost' for table 'tablename'
```

I even tried other commands such as GRANT CREATE or GRANT DROP, the same error keep showing.

```
ERROR 1142 (42000): CREATE,GRANT command denied to user 'newuser'@'localhost' for table 'tablename'
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Possibly forgot to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You logged into MySQL as root and created the new user, but you need to grant the permissions to the new user as well while logged in as root. Then you'll be able to login as newuser and execute statements.